# OpenCL pass local memory

Tags: opencllink

I've got the following OpenCL function:

```
__kernel void mergeSort(__global const float * in,__global float * out, __local float *aux)
```

When I try to call it, I only receive an internal error

```
OpenCLFunction::invprop: OpenCLLink encountered an invalid property.
```

I've allocated the memory with

```
OpenCLMemoryAllocate["Float", 8]
```

When I remove the "__local", the kernel can be executed. The kernel works fine in a standalone C++ application.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCL specification [has this to say](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) about `clSetKernelArg` which is called internally when the arguments are passed in:

> If the argument is declared with the __local qualifier, the arg_value entry must be NULL.

When you allocate using `OpenCLMemoryAllocate`, you are setting that pointer to something non-null, and you are allocating global memory.

Do not use `OpenCLMemoryAllocate` for this. Instead, remove the `aux` argument and handle this inside the kernel:

```
__kernel void mergeSort(__global const float * in,__global float * out)
{
    __local float aux[8];    
    ...
}
```

I have dug into the Mathematica packages and found this in `SystemFiles/Links/GPUTools/WGLPrivate.m`

```
SetKernelLocalMemoryArgument[size_Integer] :=
    Module[{res},
        res = cSetLocalMemoryArgument[size];
        If[SuccessQ[res],
            res,
            Throw[$Failed]
        ]
    ]
```

... which appears to do what we want. However, I see no way to call this hidden function.

---

The Mathematica documentation also says:

> Use of memory modifiers such as __constant is not supported by OpenCLLink. Memory passed into an OpenCLFunction must be __global.